# C printing second value of string for both strings

Tags: c, string, printf

```
for(j=0;j<nodes;j++){

        //changes source node from number to charcter           
        if(j==0){char nod[1] = "A";}
        else if(j==1){char nod[1] = "B";}
        else if(j==2){char nod[1] = "C";}
        else if(j==3){char nod[1] = "D";}
        else if(j==4){char nod[1] = "E";};

        int d = rt[i].from[j]+1;

        if(d==1){char nod[1] = "A";}
        else if(d==2){char next[1] = "B";}
        else if(d==3){char next[1] = "C";}
        else if(d==4){char next[1] = "D";}
        else if(d==5){char next[1] = "E";};

        printf("\t\n %s %d %s ",nod,rt[i].dist[j],next);

}
```

This prints out the same for both strings, and it prints out next and does not print out nod at all.
ie.

```
For router A
A 0  A  
B 2  B  
C 3  C  
C 5  C  
B 5  B
```

when it should look like:

```
For router A
A 2  A  
B 0  B  
C 4  C  
D 4  C  
E 3  B
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `nod` and `next` appear to be out of scope?

Comment: The one line `if` didn't let me notice that, but indeed they are.

Comment: Time to google for the word "scope" in the context of programming :)

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring `nod` and `next` in each if block, and when the block ends, they go out of scope.

So you are not printing the modified `nod` or `next`, but one that is declared before this `for` loop starts.

You don't need `nod` or `next` just to print the values, you could print them directly or,

```
for(j=0;j<nodes;j++)
{
    int d = rt[i].from[j] + 1;
    printf("\t%c %d %c\n", 'A' + d - 1, rt[i].dist[j], 'A' + d - 1);
}
```

would give you the ouput that you want.

Comment: if I take out all of the declartions of d and replace next with rt[i].from[j]+1 then nod works fine but then I'm left with numbers instead of letters for rt[i].from[j]+1